# How to Shape Text?

Tags: graphics, style, number-representation, string-manipulation

Imagine I have a certain number

```
23819657294172004194219023914217958273128471531429470113
```

If I convert it to a string with `ToString`, is it possible to present it in a specific shape, for example a rectangle, triangle, or a circle/ellipse? Ideally I would like to, given a fixed convex region, find a way to to fit the number there. For instance, get something like

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: fyi, [algorithm-for-text-wrapping-within-a-shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048305/algorithm-for-text-wrapping-within-a-shape)

Comment: [`WordCloud`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCloud.html) has the built-in ability to fit text into a shape. You could also use `ScalingFunctions -> (1&)` to keep all digits the same size. However, I am not sure how you could "convince" it to display repeated digits as different, and to keep the digits in the original order when doing so. Perhaps it may be possible to just access the internal algorithm to fit text into a shape...